# How to increase or decrease web browser font size using button in windows phone?

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, xml-parsing

Hi am using code given below.I want to increase or decrease text font size on web browser using A+ and A- buttons.i am getting html file from xml feed.so any one help to resolve in this solution.

```
<phone:WebBrowser x:Name="webBrowser" Height="592"  IsScriptEnabled="True" />
<Button BorderThickness="0"   Margin="0,0,18,0" Height="88" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="96" x:Uid="#aPlus" Click="A-_Click" >
```

```
private void A-_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (i > 2)
    {
        webBrowser.FontSize -= 2;
        i++;
        j = i;
    }
}

private void A+_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (i < 3)
    {
        webBrowser.FontSize += 2;
        i++;
        j = i;
    }
}

<Fullcontent>
    <html>
        <body>
            <p>When worn right, there&rsquo;s nothing quite like gold and Shilpa seems to have pulled off the look in style on Nach Baliye 5. Other stars spotted were Ajay Devgn and Akshay Kumar with Kajal Agarwal promoting their film Special 26. Though Kajal looked pretty in an Anarkali, she could not quite compete with Shilpa.</p>
        </body>
    </html>
</Fullcontent>

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    string selectedIndex = "";
    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("selectedItem", out selectedIndex))
    {
        webBrowser.NavigateToString(App.CurrentArticle.FullContent);
    }
}
```

I am using this code but nothing to change font size.so help me any one how to solve in this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use WebBrowser.InvokeScript:

```
// Initial text size
int textSize = 100; // Percentage

private void A+_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textSize *= 2; // Can modify to not increase so much each time
    string szfn = "{styleText = \"body { -ms-text-size-adjust:" + textSize + "% }\";styleTextNode = document.createTextNode(styleText);styleNode = document.createElement(\"style\");styleNode.appendChild(styleTextNode);document.getElementsByTagName(\"head\")[0].appendChild(styleNode);};";
    webBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", szfn);
}

private void A-_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textSize /= 2; // Can modify to not decrease so much each time
    string szfn = "{styleText = \"body { -ms-text-size-adjust:" + textSize + "% }\";styleTextNode = document.createTextNode(styleText);styleNode = document.createElement(\"style\");styleNode.appendChild(styleTextNode);document.getElementsByTagName(\"head\")[0].appendChild(styleNode);};";
    webBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", szfn);
}
```

Check out [this post on MSDN.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-us/abeb203d-eb6d-4297-8c93-6762b12036c6/font-size-not-setting-in-web-browser-control-in-windows-phone-8?forum=wpdevelop)